# SQL - How can I clone my rows, changing only one field?

Tags: sql, csv, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using SQL with pyspark and hive, and I'm new to all of it.
I have a problem in my hands that I don't know how to solve.

If I have a table "People" , like this:

```
id |  name   | other_names
1  |  Alice  | Sarah;Tom
2  |  Bob    | Jane;Michael;Ben
3  | Lizzie  | John
```

The number of names in "other_names" column is variable. It can be 1,2,3,....

I want to create a query to obtain this:

```
id   |  name
1    |  Alice
1    |  Sarah
1    |  Tom
2    |  Bob 
2    |  Jane
2    |  Michael
2    |  Ben
3    |  Lizzie
3    |  John
```

Is there a not too complicated way to do this?

Thank you so so much in advance, and happy coding :D

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a "semi-colon rule based separated list" as one of your columns, but you wish to present the distinct "other_names" as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the csv string into rows, you can make a lateral join and use `split()` and `explode()`:

```
select t.id, n.other_name
from mytable t
lateral view explode(split(t.other_names, ';')) n as other_name
```

If you also wanted the primary name:

```
select id, name from mytable
union all
select t.id, n.other_name
from mytable t
lateral view explode(split(t.other_names, ';')) n as other_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from **`Spark-2.4+:`**

We can use **`array_union`** to make `names,other_names` columns into one array.

- Then **`explode`** the column to create `name` column.
- We don't have to `union all` two tables/dataframes

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","Alice","Sarah;Tom"),("2","Bob","Jane;Micheal;Ben"),("3","Lizzie","John")],["id","name","other_names"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("new",array_union(array(col("name")),split(col("other_names"),";"))).\
select("id",explode("new").alias("name")).\
show()

#+---+-------+
#| id|   name|
#+---+-------+
#|  1|  Alice|
#|  1|  Sarah|
#|  1|    Tom|
#|  2|    Bob|
#|  2|   Jane|
#|  2|Micheal|
#|  2|    Ben|
#|  3| Lizzie|
#|  3|   John|
#+---+-------+
```